# Private constructor in abstract class

Tags: java, class, constructor, private, abstract

In Java what is the purpose of using private constructor in an abstract class?

In a review I got this question, and I am curious, for what situation we need to use the constructor in such way?

I think it can be used in pair with another constructor in abstract class, but this is very trivial. Also it can be used for constructing static inner classes which will excend abstract class.

Maybe there is more elegant usage?

Comment: I didn't vote on this question but I suspect the people downvoting are objecting to *"Maybe there is more elegant usage"* - that's pretty broad and sounds quite rhetorical.

Comment: The question is: *" In Java what is the purpose of using private constructor in abstract class?"*. That seems specific enough to me.

Comment: when you get questions like this in interviews, there usually isn't one right answer. The interviewer might simply be looking to test your thought process.

Comment: If you change the initial question to "In Java what is the purpose of using a private no-argument constructor in an abstract class?" then there is a good answer.  It is to force sub-classes to provide constructors which match the signature of another constructor in the abstract class which contains required parameters.  The compiler will enforce this which helps to prevent errors in subclasses.   If the question is re-opened I can provide detailed example code.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If the `private` constructor is the **only** constructor of the class, then the reason is clear: to prevent subclassing. Some classes serve only as holders for static fields/methods and do not want to be either instantiated or subclassed. Note that the `abstract` modifier is in this case redundant—with or without it there would be no instantiation possible. As @JB Nizet notes below, the `abstract` modifier is also bad practice because it sends wrong signals to the class's clients. The class should in fact have been `final`.

There is another use case, quite rare though: you can have an `abstract class` with only `private` constructors that contains its own subclasses as nested classes. This idiom makes sure those nested classes are the only subclasses. In fact, `enum`s in Java use just this idiom.

If there are other constructors around, well then there's really nothing special about the `private` constructor. It gets used in an `abstract` class just as in any other.

Comment: I would say that using abstract in this case is not only redundant, but confusing. An abstract class, by definition, is *meant* to be subclassed. Making a class abstract, but not subclassable, shows a lack of understanding of what abstract is for.

Comment: @JBNizet Not necessarily lack of understanding, but maybe lack of care not to confuse your clients. BTW note my second paragraph that I've just added. This gives perfect motivation for the `private` ctor in an `abstract` class.

Answer (score 7):

Only thing I can think of is reusing common code shared by the other (protected) constructors. They could then call the private constructor in their first line.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, the default no-arg constructor is made private, and another constructor which accepts arguments is provided. This constructor might then invoke other private constructor(s) .  This forces implementations to supply these arguments, which might ensure some variable is always initialized, although this is not common practice (in my experience). If this is the requirement, you would be better off checking your variables and throwing an `IllegalArgumentExeption`, explaining why the variable needs to be initialized.

If you create an abstract class with *only* private constructors, the class is practically useless as no instances can ever be created. If the intention is to create a utility class with only static methods (like the `Math` class in the `java.lang` package), private constructors are acceptable, however the class should be marked final instead, as marking the class as abstract implies the class is to be extended.

Comment: However, if you provide just one constructor explicitly, there is no default no-arg constructor, so this is not really a reason to make it private.

Answer (score 2):

1. As mentioned, to be used as a common, internal-use only constructor.
2. Abstract or not abstract, it's not uncommon to declare a private default constructor on a class containing only static public methods [helper methods] to prevent instantiating the class.

Comment: @Thilo - I agree (3) doesn't apply, I got carried away - that would be an extension of (1).  4 is qualified to clarify that it's not directly applicable to the specific question.

Answer (score 0):

no other elegant use is possible

Answer (score 0):

A private constructor in an abstract class can also serve the purpose of `sealed` classes (like in Scala or Kotlin etc.). Since you can still provide subclasses from within the abstract class, but outsiders cannot extend/implement (as @Marko Topolnik answered).

It does look like we will be getting `sealed interface` to more cleanly support this. See https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8222777

Answer (score 0):

A final class with only private constructors is a design used by singletons and multitons.

An abstract class which has only private constructors is the only way I've seen to prevent a class from being instantiated.  I have seen it used to create utility classes (which only have static methods and/or members).

As for setting up user expectations I see that https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html states "Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they **can be** subclassed."  I note that it does not state any intention that they are expected to be subclassed.

I also note however that viewing some Java source code I find the following designs are used (none of which are abstract classes with only private constructors):

- Final utility classes with private constructors

  - http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Math-source.html
  - http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/System-source.html
- Final utility classes with private constructors which
  throw exceptions

  - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java
- Neither abstract nor final utility classes with private constructors

  - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayPrefixHelpers.java
  - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java
  - https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java
  - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/FormattableFlags.java
- Looks like a utility, but apparently can be instantiated (no private
  constructors)

  - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/ArraysParallelSortHelpers.java